# Regex for reformatting a string to a safe xml-tag

Tags: xml, regex

I'm currently trying to write a RegexReplace to ensure an input can be used as a valid XML-tag, meaning: no spaces, no special characters, only lowercase, etc...

Is there a common approach to that or do I have to do it all from scratch?

Example:

```
string Invalid = "asd(%4 asKUd n!%mn &§a_As1";  // Invalid as a tag

string Valid = FormatToSafeXmlTag(Invalid);  // How to write this function?

// Valid = "asd4_askud_nmna_as1"
```

Comment: You could check if a XML parser can read the string...

Comment: @Welbog - This is a much smaller case than that, and regex would probably work fine.  If I'm reading the question right, he's just validating that something would be a valid tag name.  That's a *much* smaller problem than seeing if something is valid XML.  The rules for a valid tag name are probably simple.

Comment: He isn't trying to parse xml with regex - just trying to validate the user input to use it as an xml tag. Sounds like a valid usecase for regex to me.

Comment: Actually, I don't event want to evaluate if the tag is acceptable - I want to accept it and use it, but format it so, that it's valid. E.g. if the user inputs `asd(%4 asKUd n!%mn &§a_As1`, the Regex should return `asd4_askud_nmna_as1` as a valid tag.

Comment: @Herms and Amarghosh: Noted. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name), an element's name is formed in the following way:

```
Name   ::=  NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

Where

```
NameStartChar  ::=  ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] 
  | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] 
  | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] 
  | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
NameChar       ::=  NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 
  | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

Which is trivial to convert to a regular expression.

If you're looking to remove any character outside of this definition, simply invert the characters the expression is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

- Only lowercase: `^[a-z]+$`
- First char lowercase,  (optional) remaining chars lowecase/numbers `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$`
- Only uppercase: `^[A-Z]+$`
- First char alphabet, (optional) remaining chars alphanumeric `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

EDIT: To trim off everything but lowercase characters in javascript:

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
```

The catch is when users enters nothing but unacceptable characters - you will end up trying to create an xml tag with an empty string. I'd rather ask user to try again - how hard it can be to enter a lowercase string?

**CAUTION:** Another edge case is when user enters `xml` or any case-insensitive variants thereof (thanks to @Tim's answer). If you are on javascript, you cannot use the solution suggested by Tim, as it uses lookbehind, a feature unsupported by the javascript regex.

JavaScript code:

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, "_"); //replaces spaces

str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/g, "");//trim symbols

var reg = new RegExp(/^xml/i); 

if(str.length == 0 || reg.test(str)) //is it empty or "xml" or "XmL" or ..
    alert("invalid regex");
```

Comment: Are single character tags OK? (Your second and last examples will only match tags with multiple characters)

Comment: @ApoY2k What if user enters only invalid characters?

Answer (score 2):

XML tags (I assume you're asking about tag names) have to follow these rules:

- start with letter, dot, colon or underscore
- only contain letters, numbers, dot, underscore or colon (for namespaces)
- must not start with `xml`

Therefore, a regex for valid tag names could be:

```
^(?!xml)[\w.:][\w\d.:]*$
```

depending on your regex flavor (e.g., .NET includes Unicode letters in `\w`, as is legal for a tag name). You could also use

```
^(?!xml)[p\{L}._:][\p{L}\p{N}._:]*$
```

if `\w` doesn't contain Unicode letters.

But of course you can use more restrictive rules, and possibly not all XML parsers can handle full Unicode tag names. So in the end,

```
^(?!xml)[A-Za-z._:][A-Za-z0-9._:]*$
```

might be your best bet...

Comment: where do you get that it must not start with "xml"?  I don't think that is in the spec.  See Welbog's answer.

Comment: I read that here: http://de.selfhtml.org/xml/dtd/bearbeitungsregeln.htm#namen (sorry, it's in German) where it says that `xml` is reserved for later extensions of the standard.

Comment: AFAIK, `xml`-tags are reserved for, well.. xml-specific tags^^

Comment: There is of course the "xml" tag at the beginning of xml docs, but the spec does not place a restriction on those tags that begin with "xml".  Again see the grammar that welbog posted.